# Adding JButtons and such in bulk

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I was wondering if there was a better way to add JButton to  JPanel or Container etc. 
for example, 
instead of

```
p1.add(b1);
p1.add(b2);
p1.add(b3);
```

Could you do this, or something like that?

```
p1.add(b1,b2,b3);
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer how would you do that? I dont seem to understand how

Comment: Why not simply write a for loop and try it out? You've nothing to lose and all to gain. The key would be learning about how the layout managers work, and then using them to your advantage.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how would one learn how they work? Is there documentation explaining it, or is it just trial and error?

Comment: Google [Java Layout Manager Tutorial](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java+swing+layout+manager+tutorial), first hit -- bingo.

Answer (score 5):

Put your buttons in List or array and use a loop to add them to the container.

You could also create a method which used variable arguments

```
public void addAll(JComponent... comps) {
    for (JComponent comp : comps) {
        add(comp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, could I also do this with adding actionlisteners and other event listensers?